# Identity server 4 windows authentication using extension Grant not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have set-up Identity server 4 for client credentials and Implicit flows and all are working fine.Now I have written an extension grant to support windows authentication but it always return false from AuthenticateAsync in the ValidateAsync method.

My problem is same as the one mentioned in this post [IdentityServer4 Resource owner password and Win auth: unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57273372/identityserver4-resource-owner-password-and-win-auth-unauthorized?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but none answered that post

```
public class WinAuthGrantValidator : IExtensionGrantValidator
    {
        private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;
        private readonly IClientSecretValidator _clientValidator;

        public string GrantType => "CustomWindowsAuth";

        public WinAuthGrantValidator(IClientSecretValidator clientValidator,IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            _clientValidator = clientValidator;
        }

        public async Task ValidateAsync(ExtensionGrantValidationContext context)
        {
            // validate client
            var clientResult = await _clientValidator.ValidateAsync(_httpContext);
            if (clientResult.Client == null)
            {
               // _httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidClient);
                return;
            }

            var result = await _httpContext.AuthenticateAsync(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName);
            if (result?.Principal is WindowsPrincipal wp)
            {
                var roles = wp.Claims.ToList();

                var id = new ClaimsIdentity(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName);
                id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, wp.Identity.Name));
                id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, wp.Identity.Name));
                if (AccountOptions.IncludeWindowsGroups)
                {
                    var wi = wp.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
                    var groups = wi?.Groups?.Translate(typeof(NTAccount),false);
                    if (groups != null)
                    {
                        roles = groups.Select(x => new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, x.Value)).ToList();
                        id.AddClaims(roles);
                    }
                }
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(wp.Identity.Name, GrantType, roles);

            }
            else
            {

                await _httpContext.ChallengeAsync(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName);
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.UnauthorizedClient, "Invalid credential");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the identity server registration for the above

```
services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
            {
                iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
                iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
            });

  var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {

                    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                })
                .AddSigningCredential(Certificate.Certificate.LoadCertificateFromStore(thumbPrint, logger))
                .AddAspNetIdentity<TUserIdentity>()
                .AddIdentityServerStoresWithDbContexts<TConfigurationDbContext, TPersistedGrantDbContext>(configuration)
                 .AddExtensionGrantValidator<WinAuthGrantValidator>()
                .AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>();
```

this is the code from client

```
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true
    });

    var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(new DiscoveryDocumentRequest
    {
        Address = "http://marsdevhv020.identity.marsdev.co.nz",
        Policy =
        {
            RequireHttps = false
        }
    });

    var tokenResponse = await client.RequestTokenAsync(new TokenRequest
    {
        Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
        GrantType = "CustomWindowsAuth",
        ClientId = "WindowsClient",
        ClientSecret = "WindowsClientSecret",
        Parameters =
        {
            { "scope", "TestApi.Read" }
        }
    });


    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit!");
        Console.Read();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
```

It always return error as always result?.Principal is null

Comment: What is the error? This is not enough to help you.

Comment: Hello As mentioned already the result.Principal is always null when Httpcontext.AuthenticateAsync is executed where as the windows credentials passed from console client correctly. If it authenticating windows correctly I would expect the windows principal from authenticate method.. does that better explains about the problem I have?

Answer (score 0):

ChallengeAsync doesn't appear to work correctly when being used in a custom grant validator. You can get around it with custom middleware:

```
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await httpContext.ChallengeAsync("Windows");
            }
            else
            {
                 await _next(httpContext);
            }
        }
```

This will force authentication before getting to your validator, where the principle should now be set.