# Problem with custom claims when Windows authentication is used

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to implement Windows authentication for Identity Server 4.

In my code, I use similar solutions to the one described in [Identity server 4 windows authentication using extension Grant not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517535/identity-server-4-windows-authentication-using-extension-grant-not-working)

First of all, I use the `HttpSys` server with a proper scheme

```
builder.WebHost.UseHttpSys(options =>
{
    options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate | AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;;
    options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;    
});
```

then I add `Negotiate` for Authentication:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {        
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.ApiName = "server.api";
    })
    .AddNegotiate()
    .AddLocalApi();
```

I also extend Identity Server with such code:

```
.AddExtensionGrantValidator<WinAuthGrantValidator>()
```

(the code of `WinAuthGrantValidator` can be found in this answer  [Identity server 4 windows authentication using extension Grant not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517535/identity-server-4-windows-authentication-using-extension-grant-not-working))

This seems to work and the user is authenticated. `WindowsIdentity` is in `HttpContext.User.Identity` - so far, so good.

Now is my problem, I have also registered `ProfileService` in the Identity Server 4 like so:

```
.AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
```

which adds some data to the logged in user (as an additional Claim) - this works if the user is logged in with username and password.

Unfortunately when I use Windows Authentication for logging, then `ProfileService` is invoked and adds some claims to `IssuedClaims` but later (in application code) I try to read those Claims from `HttpContext.User` it doesn't have it. Would you help me figure out why this is happening?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What kind of `IssuedClaims` you want to get from `HttpContext.User`?After Windows authentication,you can try to get the additional information you want with [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456523/quick-way-to-retrieve-user-information-active-directory).

Comment: I want to have there `IssuedClaim` that is added in the ProfileService - it's a claim with our internal id, that I can use to connect this user with our logging/db systems